# How to add custom data validator directly without specialized directive?

Tags: angularjs, validation

In short I would like to have a custom data validator without writing entire directive for it.

Here is my case -- I have editor component/directive with several input fields. Let's say (this is content of the template of editor directive):

```
<input ng-model="phrase"></input>
<input ng-model="translation"></input>
```

The "classic" approach would be to write:

```
<input ng-model="translation" validator-1 validator-2 validator-3... ></input>
```

and add appropriate directives for those validators. But I don't like this approach, because those validators are not general purpose, they are tailored for this template only, and adding them suggests there is some kind of composition (that it would be almost OK to change something), and it is not true -- there is atomic entity "input + validators" = "translation".

Thus I would like to add custom validator directly into the code of my editor directive.

How to do it?

*So far I was experimenting with finding out what is inside `ngModel` of my editor directive, but since the editor directive does not have model for entire editor, just for distinct fields (as shown above) I failed at requiring `ngModel` for my editor.*

Comment: Want to check I understand this correctly, are you looking to loosen the dependency of a specific input to its validation logic? i.e `input + {V1,V2,V3} = translation` could be `input + {V4,V2,V5} = translation` in other instances?

Comment: @DavidBarker, well, it could be `input + {V4,V2,V5}` but it would not be translation input. Maybe I added too much theory :-) What I want is simply more compact editor directive -- just it (i.e. editor) directive, without bunch of auxiliary directives coming along. So I would like rather to say "hey, validate this data" (in JS code), instead "hey, validate this html input control with data bound to it" (in HTML template).

Comment: If I understand well, maybe something like [egkyron](https://github.com/nikospara/egkyron) suites your needs. If you check the [Angular example](https://github.com/nikospara/egkyron/tree/master/src/examples/angular), you will see that it does require a `validate` directive next to each `ng-model`, but that's that - all actual validation is declared in the code. The `validate` directive and its collaborators bind the validation results to the UI.